# Unity calculate quaternion relative to main camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have world coordinates for GameObject object and for Camera.main and I would like to calculate position and rotation relative to Camera.main.
Position is easy:

object.transform.position - Camera.main.transform.position

How to calculate Quaternion for given object relative to camera ?

I can set object.transform.parent = Camera.main.transform and read localRotation, but is there more elegant solution.

Comment: `Transform.LookAt()` the object, then read back the rotation.

Comment: @3Dave That doesn't answer the question. `Transform.LookAt` doesn't give a relative rotation from one rotation to another. It gives a rotation that points one transform at another. The current rotations of the transforms don't affect the changes made by `Transform.LookAt` at all.

Comment: @Ruzihm Copy `Camera.main.transform`, make a new transform from that and `.LookAt` the object. Subtract the two Euler angles. Getting the quat from that is trivial. The real issue here (from my Pov) is that "relative rotation" isn't really well-defined, but this is one (in my opinion, valid) interpretation.

Comment: @3Dave That usually gives a very different result from setting `object.transform.parent = Camera.main.transform;` and reading `object.transform.localRotation`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition:

> ```
> obj.transform.parent.rotation * obj.transform.localrotation = obj.transform.rotation
> ```

So, another way of phrasing your question is that you want to find the quaternion `q` such that `Camera.main.transform.rotation * q == object.transform.rotation`. So, you can solve this algebraically:

> ```
>                         cam_rotation * q = obj_rotation  
> inverse(cam_rotation) * cam_rotation * q = inverse(cam_rotation) * obj_rotation  
>                                        q = inverse(cam_rotation) * obj_rotation
> ```

And to calculate that in unity:

```
Quaternion q = Quaternion.Inverse(Camera.main.transform.rotation) 
               * object.transform.rotation;
```